# Generative Adversarial Network Converging Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am a beginner in the field of Deep Learning. I am trying to develop a 'Generative Adversarial Network' following an example given in the TensorFlow website. Unfortunately, I am getting some errors and could not make it run. I am here posting the code up to which it can be executed and also providing the error that needs to be addressed.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout 
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU 
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D 
from keras.models import Sequential, Model 
from keras.optimizers import SGD 

def makediag3d(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    depth, size = a.shape
    x = np.zeros((depth,size,size))
    for i in range(depth):
        x[i].flat[slice(0,None,1+size)] = a[i]
   return x

input = pd.read_excel( '3_height.xls')
new_input = (makediag3d(input))
output = pd.read_excel( '3_absor.xls')
new_output= np.array(output)
```

BUFFER_SIZE = 50000
BATCH_SIZE = 128
train_dataset =

tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(new_input).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(3*3*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(50,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((3, 3, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256)
    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides(1,1),padding='same',  use_bias=False)) 
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 3, 3, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5),strides(2,2),padding='same', 
    use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 3, 3, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2),padding='same',  

    use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 3, 3, 1)

    return model
generator = make_generator_model()

def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                 input_shape=[3, 3, 1]))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))

    return model
discriminator = make_discriminator_model()

cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
                             discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
                             generator=generator,
                             discriminator=discriminator)
```

The error I get:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-0106cda2248f> in <module>
      3 checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
      4                                  discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
----> 5                                  generator=generator,
      6                                  discriminator=discriminator)
      7 

NameError: name 'generator' is not defined
```

I am also providing the link of the entire code for your kind perusal.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VJOARa9XvPWtcjQFbd0jATLsbkeEzJcl/view?
usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be better to post here the traceback of specific error and the relevant piece of code where it occurs. It is recommended to narrow down the problem in your question to help others help you. Also it is better to post code right in the question as external source may change in time (especially Google Docs).

Comment: I have edited my post as per your suggestion. Please share your valuable comments.